# Visual Studio + Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Esta vez les escribo para hacerles una consulta. He hecho un programita muy sencillo que tiene 2 labels adentro de un `stacklayout`. Estoy usando `databinding` pero me sale esto error al compilar y no me doy cuenta que puede ser.

> IDE0006    Error al cargar el proyecto. Se han deshabilitado algunas de sus características, como el análisis completo de la solución para el proyecto que ha dado error y los proyectos dependientes.

¿Me pueden dar una mano?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Raulus.

Answer (score 0):

¿Seguro que es un error? Hasta donde he visto, se trata de un "warning".

Lo que sucede:

Visual studio/xamarin verifica el requisito de las "sdkbuild tools" para tu proyecto.

- Si lo tienes, entonces se ejecuta sin problemas.
- Si no lo tienes, tu proyecto te lanzará ese warning en la mayoría de casos.

Soluciones:

1. Dale un Clean a tu solución.
2. Ahora un Rebuild, con esto comenzará una descarga de los zips.
3. En caso el Rebuild se cancele por error, cierra el Visual Studio y abres visual studio y de nuevo paso 1 y 2.

O la alternativa más simple de todas:

- Descarga todas las SDKBuild tools disponibles.

Sugerencia:

Descarga e instala el SDK Manager desde aquí: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinAndroidSDKManager y te dejo la documentación para que te diviertas aprendiendo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin

Referencias:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649002/3613462

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2016/08/10/using-the-correct-version-of-android-sdk-build-tools-with-xamarin-android/

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas. Voy a probar lo que dice fredyfx y NaCI. Muchas gracias de nuevo....

Comment: Ahí pude compilar!! Lamentablemente cuando corro la app, me levanta el emulador y todo pero no muestra nada de la app. Son solo dos labels...

Comment: @Raulus si lograste compilar (el problema principal que tienes) ¿podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada? El otro problema que mencionas es otra pregunta. Saludos :D